# Unable to install Doorkeeper-MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, doorkeeper

I have a fresh installation of rails 4 with MongoMapper. Now i'm trying to install doorkeeper on my rails instance.

I added the "gem 'doorkeeper-mongodb'" line in my Gemfile. Then I ran 'bundle install'. And I got the following error :

```
Could not find gem 'doorkeeper-mongodb (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

Also, I tried to install it using the gem install command but it doesn't work either.

I'm on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The line to put in the Gemfile is

```
gem 'doorkeeper-mongodb', github: 'doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-mongodb'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried checking the gems in [https://rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=doorkeeper-mongodb) and could not find doorkeeper-mongodb.
And then googled out, and found that if you want to install gems from github source, then the right way seems like this following:

```
gem 'doorkeeper-mongodb', :git => 'git://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-mongodb.git'
```

Or you can also download the source from github, and install it from local.